# How do I do exponents in Scheme?

Tags: scheme

`pow`, `^`, `**` doesn't work, and Scheme seems to be too common a word to be able to effectively google it.

Answer (score 30):

From [R5RS Standard Pocedures](http://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-9.html#%_idx_314):

> ```
> (expt z1 z2) 
>
> Returns z1 raised to the power z2. For z1 0
>
> z1z2 = ez2 log z1
>
> 0z is 1 if z = 0 and 0 otherwise.
> ```

Searching for "scheme reference" turns up this document.

Answer (score 15):

The answer is `expt` and I am typing because StackOverflow doesn't like too short answers.

Answer (score 8):

`(expt base power)` is what you want. So `(expt 2 3)` expresses 2^3 and yields 8.